# Where is function for remove image from admin of product

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, product-images, delete

I want to know function logic location, when product image is remove from admin section. The checkbox is present in "images" tab. After check checkbox of images in "Remove" column and hit save or save and continue which functions calls in both cases for remove images which are assigned to product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media::beforeSave()`

```
foreach ($value['images'] as &$image) {
    if(!empty($image['removed'])) {
        $clearImages[] = $image['file'];
    } else if (!isset($image['value_id'])) {
        $newFile                   = $this->_moveImageFromTmp($image['file']);
        $image['new_file'] = $newFile;
        $newImages[$image['file']] = $image;
        $this->_renamedImages[$image['file']] = $newFile;
        $image['file']             = $newFile;
    } else {
        $existImages[$image['file']] = $image;
    }
}
```

So if the remove checkbox is checked this will return true `if(!empty($image['removed'])) {` then the image is marked for deleteing.

Later on this is executed based on the images that are removed (`$clearImages`):

```
if (in_array($attrData, $clearImages)) {
    $object->setData($mediaAttrCode, 'no_selection');
}
```

**[EDIT]**

There is also this code in the same class in the `afterSave` method:

```
if(!empty($image['removed'])) {
    if(isset($image['value_id']) && !isset($picturesInOtherStores[$image['file']])) {
        $toDelete[] = $image['value_id'];
    }
    continue;
}
```

And later this is called `$this->_getResource()->deleteGallery($toDelete);`.
Maybe this one is what you are looking for.

Comment: If i use die; for printing $clearImages, my page is not stop and image is also deleted why?

Comment: See my update.  If that's not either, look for `removed` in the catalog module. That's how the input is called.

Comment: Yes i am looking for the same. :)